# Installing Magento in local: "Agree and Setup" Button is missing

Tags: magento, xampp

I'm trying to install magento in local.. I created a db with phpmyadmin called "magento" and put the magento files in a folder named "magento" in htdocs but when I open the address htdocs/magento in the browser i see this screen:
magento2.4
magento screen without button

[image: splash screen without setup button]

but I dont't see the button "agree and install magento".. how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the 2.4 release of Magento, GUI based installation has been removed. You need to install Magento by CLI (as it actually says in your screenshot).

Docs to install Magento via CLI can be found here:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

A tutorial on how to install Magento 2.4 with elasticsearch can be found here:

https://magentip.com/install-magento-2-on-localhost-xampp-elasticsearch/